# Document partial parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, documentation, comments

Is there any standard or emerging standard to document the parameters that can be passed into a Rails partial ?

When `_my_partial.html.erb` expects a `title` and an `elements` local var passed with `render 'my_partial', title: t, elements: e`, there must be a common way to document their names, expected types and roles, without reading the whole partial code. Something like RDoc or Tomdoc for methods and classes. Isn't there ?

Edit: I've found [a post](http://killswitchcollective.com/articles/13_best_practices_for_rails_partials) whose author advocates initializing parameters with `<% var ||= 'default_val' %>` in the first lines of the partial, which is indeed a safe practice and a kind of in-code doc. Is there really no comment/parameter-declaration solution for this ?

Comment: I'd document a helper method rendering the partial

Comment: I start my partials with an
<% if false %>
  <%= render all_the_correct_parameters_and_stuff %>
<% end %>

Comment: @AlbinSvensson why?! just use (multiline) comments http://ionrails.com/2010/02/05/multiline-comments-in-rails-erb-views/

Comment: Nice, did not know that existed. But will be using it from now on. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning of your partial, simply call all the variables that are referenced.

```
# _my_partial.html.erb
<% title %>            <---  first line of file
<% elements[0] %>

<h3><%= title %></h3>
<% elements.each do |element| %>
   <p> etc ... </p>
```

### Reasons why this is good for your project:

- it does not rely on comments or non-code files
- any developer on the project can quickly find out which variables are needed by looking at the top of the file in question
- by calling the variables, you ensure that a missing variable will result in an exception.
- elements is called with square brackets because we also want it to blow up if it's not an enumerable, right?

The practice of using `<% var ||= 'default_val' %>` is actually **unsafe** because it allows bugs to hide.  You want your code to *immediately blow up* the moment something isn't done right.  And if these variables should be passed, then you want the code to blow up when they're not there.

Comment: Actually, protecting the use of variable `var` in a partial with the code `<% var ||= 'default_val' %>` protects nothing if the partial depends on `var` being passed to it. If it isn't, `var` will not be even `nil` when the statement is reached, but undefined, causing an exception and an error page. (But this is all by the way, because the core of your answer is sound; I just wanted to make sure readers don't think that the statement I picked out protects anything.)